# How do I get an Acer FlatBed Scanner 22 working?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, acer, scanner

I have a scanner and I searched on Google that the Linux is the only one O.S. that have compatibility with this scanner (Acer FlatBed Scanner 22).
Before I upgrade my Ubuntu O.S. from 11.04 to 11.10 it was working, but 1 day before I upgrade it wasn`t working anymore on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bits (My other system, wich one a made DualBoot)

Someone have the same problem and could help me

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Just made my s2w 5300u working on 11.10.
Here is the instructions:

(do not forget to provide admin access if it's necessary with 'sudo')

1) Open terminal and check that system recognized scanner:

```
lsusb
```

Output:

```
Bus 007 Device 046: ID 04a5:20fe Acer Peripherals Inc. (now BenQ Corp.) SW2 5300U
```

2) Check if SANE can see the scanner:

```
scanimage -L
```

Output:

```
device `snapscan:libusb:007:045' is a Acer FlatbedScanner22 flatbed scanner
```

3) Now we have to download firmware for the scanner. Go download it from [BenQ Service & Support site](http://www.benq.co.uk/support/downloads/?productline=9)

4) Unpack 'Bin' folder from archive to, for example, your home directory.

5) Now check if folder '/usr/share/sane/firmware/' exists. If not -- create it:

```
mkdir '/usr/share/sane/firmware/'
```

6) Copy your firmware to '/usr/share/sane/firmware/':

```
cp -v '/home/user/Bin/u254v042.bin' '/usr/share/sane/firmware/'
```

***Notice**: unpacked folder 'Bin' may contents several file's and you have to choose one which suits you scanner. I did't know which one exactly and just tried a few of them. For s2w 5300u you need u254v042.bin If it'll necassery repeat steps 6, 7 with another firmwre files.*

7) It's better to establish the right to read the file for other users because it is not known with what rights were packed file:

```
sudo chmod 754 /usr/share/sane/firmware/u254v042.bin
sudo chmod o+r /usr/share/sane/firmware/u254v042.bin
```

***Notice**: I did't do this step cause it was not so necessary for me.*

8) Now we have to right path to file in config:

```
gedit /etc/sane.d/snapscan.conf
```

Find line 'firmware  /usr/share/sane/firmware/' and comment it with '##':

```
##firmware /usr/share/sane/snapscan/your-firmwarefile.bin
```

Add after this line path to your firmware file:

```
firmware /usr/share/sane/firmware/u254v042.bin
```

***Notice**: you may not comment first line. It's also can be replaced 'your-firmwarefile.bin' with 'u254v042.bin'. I think you understand.*

9) Replug your scanner. That's all.

Good luck.

[Source](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=38672.msg355375#msg355375)

Comment: As far as I can see, the firmwares are no longer available from BenQ, [so grab them from my GitHub repo](https://github.com/RobertZenz/Bivalvia/tree/master/Sane/BenQFirmwares).